# Center 2 DIV within outer DIV with text-align center + display inline-block

Tags: css, html

I followed a Q&A from other thread to center 2 DIV which is inside a div but not solve.
I added text-align center to outer DIV and display inline-block to both left and right DIV.
Pls try to let me know what is lacking...
[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZrym/106/)

HTML:

```
<div class="indexDiv" id="noPad">
<div class="results">
<div id="topResults">Top</div>
<div id="refineResults">Left</div>
<div id="listingsResults">Right</div>
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.indexDiv {
overflow: hidden;
width: 993px;
background: #ffffff;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
}

.Results {
color: #D5241B;
font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;
/*    margin: 4px 0 8px;*/
border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

.Results {
/*  padding: 10px;*/
text-align: center;
width: 930px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#topResults {
float: right;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

#refineResults {
/*  float: left;*/
width: 200px;     
display: inline-block;    
/*  padding: 5px; */
border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}

#listingsResults {
/*  float: right;*/
width: 715px;
/*  margin-left:18px;*/
border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
display: inline-block;    
/*   padding: 5px; */
}
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS class selectors are case-sensitive. You have `.Results`, which doesn't select your element with `class = "results"`. Replace it with `.results`; here's a fixed demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/MZrym/107).

Comment: text-align center making all text center but I don't want it. Any solution?

Comment: @Alouty Add `text-align: left;` to your child `divs`. (`.topResults`, `.refineResults`, ...).